Google Docs iframe slow, any faster alternatives?
I have a scenario where I implemented Google Docs Viewer using an iframe in Angular to view files, but the load time is too long, and sometimes it shows a blank screen. Is there an alternative package that supports all file types or a solution for faster file rendering?
ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  if (
    this.fileUrl.split('.').pop() === 'html' ||
    this.fileUrl.split('.').pop() === 'odt'
  ) {
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.fileUrl
    );
  } else {
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${this.fileUrl}&embedded=true`
    );
  }

  setTimeout(() => (this.isLoading = false), 2500);
}

checkIFrame(iframe: any) {
  if (iframe) {
    iframe.onload = () => {
      if (this.checkIFrameSubscription) {
        this.checkIFrameSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  }
}
reloadIFrame(iframe: any) {
  if (iframe) {
    // iframe.src = this.url;
    if (
      this.fileUrl.split('.').pop() === 'html' ||
      this.fileUrl.split('.').pop() === 'odt'
    ) {
      this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        this.fileUrl
      );
    } else {
      this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
        `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${this.fileUrl}&embedded=true`
      );
    } // Google document viewer url.
  }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let iframe = this.iframeRef ? this.iframeRef.nativeElement : null;

  this.checkIFrame(iframe);

  this.checkIFrameSubscription = interval(3000)
    .pipe(take(Math.round(20000 / 3000)))

    .subscribe(() => {
      if (iframe == null) {
        iframe = this.iframeRef
          ? this.iframeRef.nativeElement
          : null;

        this.checkIFrame(iframe);
      }

      this.reloadIFrame(iframe);
    });
  }
}

I used this code to refresh if the file fails to load but still it takes too much time.

There is an npm package, which essentially does the same by using iframe, but perhaps it got developed in a better way, which makes it load faster for ya. Take a look at ngx-doc-viewer

Yeah,I saw that but it still uses the google doc viewer.I have to implement and test,but does it support doc', 'docx', 'txt', .rtf, .odt, .html and 'pdf
